# Optimal way to install clang locally when GCC is outdated

Tags: linux, clang

I need to use tools that depend on clang on a Unix machine I remote onto at work. Anything I install is locally installed onto ~/local. I do not have root permissions.

/usr is pretty outdated, with gcc being at version 4.4.7. clang requires gcc 4.7+

I read on linux from scratch that a gcc 6.1 installation requires 8.4 gb. This is not something I can do, because that's huge.

Can someone advise me on the best workaround to install up to date clang on my ~/local?

Please and thanks.

Edit:

Courtesy of Nishant, here is the short answer:

Set up a personal machine running the same linux distro and cross compile using gcc to your specific architecture. For me, I will run a Redhat 6.5 VM and compile using gcc an arm x64 binary. Thanks Nishant!

Comment: Have you any other machine (with similar libraries) where you can compile the clang, and then just copy the installation directory to the remote ~/local directory?

Comment: I can use my work laptop running Windows 7 to try to perform a cross compilation targeting the Unix machine, is that what you are suggesting? I'd need some pointers on how to set up the Windows environment and how to target the Unix environment.

Comment: There is no such thing as "ARM x64" -- do you mean "ARM64" or "Intel/AMD x64"? -- they're two totally different things.  "x64" usually means the latter.

Comment: What? ARM and AMD both start with A. I think they are the same.

edit: +1, interesting to know there are various 64 bit ARM flavors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pre-build binaries for Unix system from LLVM's release website: http://llvm.org/releases/

You can then put the binaries in any local folder you want and source it using the PATH variable, which can be done by modifying your ~/.bashrc file by appending:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<clang-binary-directory>
```

Now you will able to use clang from the command line terminal as if it was installed.

If you want to build from source only, you can get older source code of clang which will use gcc 4.4.7 and build it and then use clang to build clang. Or get the latest clang binary and use it to build latest clang.

Comment: This is better, because it puts the custom Clang commands first to the PATH. `export "PATH=ClangBinaryDirectory:$PATH"`

Comment: The machine is running Redhat on an ARM x64 architecture. Does my binary just need to be generic linux x64, or do I need it to be tailored for Redhat? (I know it sounds dumb that I can't use 8.4 gb on this system but they're pretty stringent at work about how much space we can use, because we're always running out).

Comment: If it's Redhat, my guess is [http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.8.1] (Release 3.8.1) with Fedora23_x64 should work (You will have to confirm that). As for space, downloadable compressed files will be around 142 MB and decompression you will get something like 742 MB. I hope that's affordable for you. If not you can delete some selective files from the binaries that you don't need but let's not go there unless it's a big issue for you.

Comment: It's Redhat 6.5 which is a fork of Fedora 12, and unfortunately, there is no binary for this.

Comment: Here's what I will suggest, get Fedora 18 binary [http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.3](clang 3.3) and see if that works (if yes, you can then use that to build from source a newer version of clang). Otherwise, you will have to go for a cross compile. For that, I will say install a VM with REDHAT 6.5 on your machine and install latest gcc, build clang latest (don't build from latest commit truck or specify `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`) and then just transfer binaries to remote (no cross compilation but VM overhead).

Comment: I don't have a personal machine with an ARM x64 architecture, though. It is a shame, because I really liked the idea of having a VM on my personal computer that I can compile everything on, and stick binaries onto my work directory from it. Is it possible to compile for a different architecture on the VM?
EDIT: I guess that's what cross compilation is. It would be a good experience for me, since I've never done it before anyways.

Comment: Even if you have a windows laptop,you can use [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) to emulate ARM processor. Now, I haven't done this myself so I am sure whether you will be able to use it for cross compilation but it's a lead.

Comment: That would literally take a week to compile anything, though, and probably another week to install Redhat. You're right it is a theoretical solution - for the very patient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117344/discussion-between-nishant-sharma-and-okovko).